# Assembly Redirecting not pointing to the expected assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, gac

I am trying to do assembly redirecting in the following way:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But I am getting the following exception at runtime:

```
Inner Exception 1:
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient 
ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient.GetHttpClient()'.
```

I tried to find the modules that are loaded during runtime and I found the following:

[image]

As you can see that System.Net.Http.dll has been loaded twice and each with different version to different place. It is happenning even after I have included the assembly redirection mentioned above.

The project that I am buiding creates .dll file and it refer to several other projects with x86 build. It is based on .NET 4.6.1 and not possible to update due to other unavoidable dependencies. Cleaning and rebuilding the whole project did not help.

Any further idea to try with ?

------------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------------

The service stack is loaded as well without duplicate which I am having in System.Net.Http . Check the following screen-shot:
[image]

Comment: have you tried adding the `System.Net.Http` namespace to your project's references through the `References` node?

Comment: The error is that the ServiceStack DLL's JsonHttpClient class's `GetHttpClient()` method is missing, you might be chasing a red herring here.

Comment: If I refer from a console application that to several other projects, then I do not have this exception and only one System.Net.Http.dll is loaded during runtime -  the older from the attached snapshot